# Changing line colours in gg_miss_var

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change the line colours for each facet in gg_miss_var.

For example, using the data airquality

```
#Load data
data("airquality")

#Load libraries
library(ggplot2)

#Create missing data plot using gg plot
gg_miss_var(airquality, Month, show_pct = TRUE) + ylim(0, 100) +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    panel.border = element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("forestgreen", "pink", "blue","yellow","red"))
```

I get:
[image]

But that doesn't change the colours, any ideas?

Comment: Why would you want to change the line colors if it's already separated by facet? It doesn't add any information to the plot itself and is generally not recommended best practice.

Comment: I'd like to at least change the colour of all the lines to another colour, not necessarily by each facet, but I am unable to do that either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as a reference: While out-of-the-box options are quick and easy when it comes to customizing it might be worthwhile to build up the plot from scratch using `ggplot2` where for the data preparation you could use `naniar::miss_var_summery`:

```r
data("airquality")

library(ggplot2)
library(naniar)

df_miss <- airquality %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Month) %>% 
  miss_var_summary() |> 
  dplyr::mutate(variable = reorder(variable, pct_miss))

ggplot(df_miss, aes(pct_miss, variable, color = factor(Month))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(yend = variable, xend = 0)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("forestgreen", "pink", "blue","yellow","red"), guide = "none") +
  xlim(0, 100) +
  facet_wrap(~Month) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    panel.border = element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ggplot_build` to change the `fill` and `colour` columns of your object like this:

```r
#Load libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(naniar)
#Create missing data plot using gg plot
p <- gg_miss_var(airquality, Month, show_pct = TRUE) + 
  ylim(0, 100) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"), panel.border = element_blank()) 

q <- ggplot_build(p)
q$data[[1]]$colour <- "#D6604D"
q$data[[1]]$fill <- "#D6604D"
q$data[[2]]$colour <- "#D6604D"
q$data[[2]]$fill <- "#D6604D"
q <- ggplot_gtable(q)
plot(q)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much this works! Do you know how I can stop the bg from going grey?